# Best way to schedule many UILocalNotifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am trying to schedule many `UILocalNotification`s at the same time. I refresh a lot of data and need to cancel all previous notifications and recreate them. Currently I have this code to cancel and create the notifications:

```
- (void)scheduleNotifications {
    NSDate *start = [NSDate date];
    // Cancel old notifications
    [NotificationHandler cancelNotificationsNamed:@"ScheduleNotification"];

    if (self.user.scheduleNotifications.boolValue) {
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.user.scheduleDays.count; i++) {
            ScheduleDay *day = [self.user.scheduleDays objectAtIndex:i];
            for (SchedulePeriod *period in day.periods) {
                if (period.desc.length > 0) {
                    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitWeekday|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
                    dateComponents.day += 2 + i - dateComponents.weekday;
                    NSArray *timeComponents = [period.startTime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
                    NSInteger hour = [[timeComponents objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
                    dateComponents.hour = hour < 7 ? hour + 12 : hour; // add 12 to hour if before 7 (assume afternoon)
                    dateComponents.minute = [[timeComponents objectAtIndex:1] integerValue] - 5;
                    NSDate *fireDate = [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

                    if ([[NSDate date] compare:fireDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
                        fireDate = [fireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:604800]; // add a week if date is passed
                    }

                    [NotificationHandler scheduleNotificationNamed:@"ScheduleNotification"
                                                           forDate:fireDate
                                                           message:period.desc
                                                      repeatWeekly:YES];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%f sec", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start]);
}
```

NotificationHandler.m:

```
+ (void)scheduleNotificationNamed:(NSString *)name forDate:(NSDate *)date message:(NSString *)message repeatWeekly:(BOOL)repeatWeekly {
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.userInfo = @{@"kNotificationName" : name};
    notification.fireDate = date;
    notification.alertBody = message;
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    if (repeatWeekly) {
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}

+ (void)cancelNotificationsNamed:(NSString *)name {
    for (UILocalNotification *notification in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]) {
        if ([[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"kNotificationName"] isEqualToString:name]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it can sometimes take a few seconds to cancel and create the notifications which blocks the UI. Is there a better way?

Comment: if you are calling scheduleNotifications as [self scheduleNotifications]; then try to call this method with [self performSelector:@selector(scheduleNotifications) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.05]; this will fix the blocked UI issue.

Comment: @Deepak I am still getting a laggy interface. I don't understand how adding a delay would help with the UI blocking issue.

Comment: Some times this happen because of Higher priority task going for execution such as sqlite operation that time UI will stuck and did not update properly. So to fix such problem we can call those method after delay or in background.

Comment: @Deepak A delay didn't seem to help too much. I don't think background is an option as UI components are usually not thread safe.